# CreatedAtAction says the route doesn't exist in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm having issues getting a `CreatedAtAction` to work properly.  In my controller I have these methods:

```cs
[HttpGet("{uid:guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(Guid uid) => Ok(await _repository.GetAsync(uid));

[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> StoreAsync([FromQuery] Guid? uid, [FromBody] UpdateInputDTO data)
{
    var output = await _repository.StoreAsync(uid, data);

    if (uid is null)
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetAsync), new {
            uid = output.Uid
        });
    else
        return Ok(output);
}
```

and in my startup I did this:

```cs
services.AddControllers(x => x.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
```

But when that code runs, I always get an exception saying the route doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you try to use "Get" instead of "nameof(GetAsync)"

Comment: If you try to use `[HttpGet]` to replace `[HttpGet("{uid:guid}")]`,will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Get" instead of "nameof(GetAsync)".

> For example, the action name for ProductsController.ListProductsAsync will be canonicalized as ListProducts.. Consequently, it will be routeable at /Products/ListProducts with views looked up at /Views/Products/ListProducts.cshtml.

[SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressasyncsuffixinactionnames?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Dan, I showed in my post that I was setting that to false specifically so that it wouldn't strip the Async off.  I don't want to use a string value that will break if somebody renames the method, that's why I'm using the `nameof(GetAsync)` with SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames` set to false.

Comment: Yes. I didnt notice that.

Comment: can you make the parameter nullable GetAsync(Guid? uid). I believe it is something to do with parameter binding.